# SharedPreferences - edit object values saved on a Json file

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

So, I have an App that creates text Notes that contain a title and a description. Since I have a Class "Note" I used gsonToJson(and vice-versa) with SharedPreferences to save and load the ArrayList of Notes. The creation and saving of the notes work fine but now I want to edit the note the users choose.

Here is the code to create the Note:

```
public class TextNote_creation extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText title;
public EditText desc;
public List<Note> notes;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.textnote_create, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.confirmTextNote:

            notes = new ArrayList<>();

            String key = "notes";
            String response;

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            sharedPreferences = TextNote_creation.this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.rui.trabalhopjdm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);          


            notes.add(new Note(title.getText().toString(), title.getText().toString(), android.R.drawable.ic_menu_agenda));


            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;

            String jsonNotes = gson.toJson(notes);


            prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString(key , jsonNotes);
            prefsEditor.apply();

            Intent intent = new Intent(TextNote_creation.this, Notes.class);
            startActivity(intent);




        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_note_creation);

    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.createTitle);
    desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.createDesc);


}
}
```

In the Edit Activity, I have already the code to load the file and put it into an Array of Notes:

```
public class TextNote extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText noteEditor;
public List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();
public EditText title;
public int noteId;
public int noteIndex;



SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.save_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.saveNote:

            sharedPreferences = TextNote.this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.rui.trabalhopjdm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            for(int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++){

                if(i == noteIndex){

                    notes.get(i).setTitle(title.getText().toString());
                    notes.get(i).setDesc(noteEditor.getText().toString());
                }
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            String jsonNotes = gson.toJson(notes);




            Intent intent = new Intent(TextNote.this, Notes.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;

            default:

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_note);

    noteEditor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    noteId = intent.getIntExtra("noteId", -1);

    noteIndex = noteId - 1;

    if (noteId != -1){

        title.setText(Notes.notes.get(noteId).getTitle());
        noteEditor.setText(Notes.notes.get(noteId).getDesc());
    }

    sharedPreferences = TextNote.this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.rui.trabalhopjdm", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String key = "notes";
    String response = "";

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    response = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);

    if (response == null)
    {

    }else{

        notes = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Note>>(){}.getType());
    }


}
}
```

So, for now, I only get the Note associated with the Id I passed by the Intent and change is values, but now, how do I use those values to edit the Note saved in the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

In shared preferences the values are stored in Key value pair, so if you just save the edited value with the corresponding key then previous values will be overridden, as you are already getting the array of notes, you can do one thing save the array list in a new ArrayList and update the edited value on that index from which index you are getting the Notes, convert the new arrayList using Gson and save it into Shared Preferences.

Comment: I get it how it works now. Thanks. So, if I have a Login page, I can use the username of the account  as a Key to the Shared preferences making a ArrayList of Notes for each user right?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that thing, only thing u should remember that it should be a unique key, After log in if you are getting any userId from Server side then you can use that also

Comment: @RuiPascoal if you find the answer helpful then give it a thumbs up :)